# Calculate total CPU usage

Tags: c++, windows

What is best algorithm for calculating total CPU usage at a particular time during execution of a process.

I am working windows platform in C++.

Answer (score 2):

`GetProcessTimes` for 100-nanosecond resolution. If you want cycle times, use `QueryProcessCycleTime` in Vista and above.

Answer (score 1):

Intel VTune is a great tool for anaylzing cpu resources: http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/239144.htm

Answer (score 1):

Let me recommend you this great article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Get_CPU_Usage.aspx

I'm sure you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI to get "PercentProcessorTime"; beware that this will probably have its own performance penalty.

If you are looking to throttle your application, a better way it to have your own internal performance metric specific to your application and throttle based on that (e.g. screen refresh rate, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use WMI
Simply Use win32 NAPI

Comment: Uhm... that's was a helpful answer. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

// Declare
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = null;

// initialize somewhere in the constructor..
cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

Then to get the CPU usage in % just call
cpuCounter.NextValue()

Source:http://zamov.online.fr/EXHTML/CSharp/CSharp_927308.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method to obtains total CPU load for a period is using [GetSystemTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. It's a kernel function available starting Windows XP SP1. It returns the amount of CPU time used since system power-up. So, the difference between these values obtained during an interval will yield you total CPU usage for that interval.

Remember, that kernel time provided by this function includes 'idle' time, so you have to subtract idle time returned by first parameter from it.

The function returns total time for all cores/processors available, so you may also want to divide the deltas by the number of processors obtained from [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).