# How to detect CPU speed and H.D.D rpm in objective-c or python

Tags: python, objective-c, system-setting

I'm new to objective-c, for an academic reason I need to read CPU speed and H.D.D rpm

What is the simplest way to access some system setting in objective-c or python

I can choose between objective-c and python for this project.

Comment: Are we to assume you are looking for the information on Mac OS X?

Comment: NO, As I mentioned I need this for anacademic reason. Actually We want to check how easy or hard is accessing System informationin Python or Objective-C . and compare it with C and C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can get the reported CPU speed for Windows 2000 and up by reading the registry using python:

```
import _winreg

key = _winreg.OpenKey(
    _winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    r"HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0")

value, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "~MHz")
print 'CPU speed is:', value
```

I don't know how to do it for other operating systems nor how to get the HDD rpms though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to use a C++ module with Python to detect CPU speed or RPM of a hard drive. [Calculate total CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448811/calculate-total-cpu-usage) could help you here

I don't know anything about Obj-C, so couldn't tell you if it is possible with that language!

Answer (score 1):

Checking CPU speed isn't really an Objective C thing, it is an OS thing.   On OS X (and I assume iOS) you want to look at sysctlbyname(3) and the hw.cpufrequency property, something like:

```
int hz;
size_t hz_size = sizeof(hz);
int rc = sysctlbyname("hw.cpufrequency", &hz, &hz_size, NULL, 0);
if (0 == rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Clockspeed is %d hz\n", hz);
}
```

I don't know a good way to get the RPM of a disk drive, but I do know a bad way.   Parse the output of system_profiler, the info is in there (as "Rotational Rate"):

> ```
>     Hitachi HTS543232L9SA02:
>
>       Capacity: 320.07 GB (320,072,933,376 bytes)
>       Model: Hitachi HTS543232L9SA02                 
>       Revision: FB4AC50F
>       Serial Number: (omitted)
>       Native Command Queuing: Yes
>       Queue Depth: 32
>       Removable Media: No
>       Detachable Drive: No
>       BSD Name: disk0
>       Rotational Rate: 5400
>       Medium Type: Rotational
>       Partition Map Type: GPT (GUID Partition Table)
>       S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
>       Volumes:
>         Macintosh HD:
>           Capacity: 319.73 GB (319,728,959,488 bytes)
>           Available: 12.4 GB (12,397,940,736 bytes)
>           Writable: Yes
>           File System: Journaled HFS+
>           BSD Name: disk0s2
>           Mount Point: /
> ```

There is likely a better abstraction to use, I just don't know it.