# PDH cant access total CPU time through PdhAddCounter()

Tags: c++, pdh

i am currently trying to make some sort of CPU usage overview for my DirectX program, but it seems that i am not able to get this information through PdhAddCounter().
My code looks like this:

```
status = PdhOpenQuery(NULL, 0, &m_queryHandle);
    if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        m_canReadCpu = false;
    }

status = PdhAddCounter(m_queryHandle, TEXT("\\Processor(_Total)\\% processor time"), 0, &m_counterHandle);
    if(status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        m_canReadCpu = false;
    }
```

After the PdhAddCounter call my status is = -1073738824, wich causes the program to fail.

Im using a Windows 7 64bit system, do i have to make something different in a 64bit environment?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Remember: PdhAddCounter is locale sensible.

The response -1073738824 means PDH_CSTATUS_NO_OBJECT=0xC0000BB8. The api didn't find that string. Are you using a non-english OS?

If you need to do a Windows XP compatible application you need to use a workaround like this: http://en.verysource.com/code/3604946_1/platforminfo.cpp.html.

For Vista and Windows 7, 8,... you can use PdhAddEnglishCounter instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use [GetSystemTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) kernel32 API which will free you from the dependency on pdh.dll.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448811/calculate-total-cpu-usage/20324308#20324308).