# Determine CPU Speed / Memory in C/C++ (Linux), LGPL or BSD are a requirement

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, lgpl

I'm writing a distributed, **embedded**, multi master / slave application for my college coursework and as a part of that I need a way to determine the CPU Speed, CPU usage and available Memory of each system in **realtime** without a lot of memory respectively cpu consumption, in order to automatically adjust the configuration of the network and the devices.

Triggering system calls periodically or reading out files (open-read-close ....) does not really pose a resource friendly option. I'm sure there must be some **POSIX** compliant solution to this?

The systems will all be using **Linux** as an OS and I'm supposed to **exclusively use LGPL or BSD** libraries for the release.

So far I haven't found any solutions that would fit the criteria.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind to define _the performance_?

Comment: If you're just after CPU speed / memory, do you need a library? Can't you just look at /proc or call sysconf?

Comment: @YasushiShoji : I edited the question. I need detailsl about the CPU speed, current CPU usage and available memory of each device / system

Comment: Even with this edit, can you look in /proc or not? There's almost everything you need in there

Comment: @Rup : /proc/cpuinfo only returns total static system values, not dynamic values such as current usage.

Comment: @mmoment Actualy, if you refresh the file opening enough you ll get the actual values in real times. No files will give you a real time speed of the CPU so a way or another you have to refresh opening a /proc/file

Comment: This is not really a good way for systems with low resources. Correct me if I'm wrong, but reopening files periodically requires a load of memory and time itself?

Comment: Yes reopening a `/proc` file requires some overhead. But if you want the information to be recalculated *that* requires some overhead. On Linux `/proc` or a syscall are your only options.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`libprocps`](http://gitorious.org/procps).  It is LGPL even though many web page says it's GPL.  See [the commit log](http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/commit/ce61089)

Comment: The source code tells me the major part is GPL, though some parts of the code seem to be LGPL :/

Comment: @mmoment, does it? `git grep -l 'GNU General' **/*.[ch]` tells me four files, `free.c`, `pgrep.c`, `sysctl.c`, and `lib/strutils.c`. The commit clearly states that _"sysctl and pgrep are GPL 2+"_. Alos, it is clearly stated that it is LGPL in `free.c`.  `lib/strutils.c`, providing two functions used in a few tool but not in the library, does not state what licese it is under.  We can ask it on [procps-ng ml](http://www.freelists.org/archive/procps/) if we need.

Comment: Nice, my bad. I'll go after that.

Reading the free.c source code it says:   [...] under the terms of the GNU General Public License [...]

Comment: @mmoment, you are right. I'm sorry that I misread `+` and `-` in `git log`. free.c is under _GPL_.  I stand corrected.  By the way, you do not need `free.c` for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few tips that can lead you to a solution :

1- [kernel infos](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname)

2- You can get that information in `/proc/cpuinfo`.
Google for 'Proc Filesystems'.

3- [extract system infos](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/33551/c-program-to-extract-system-info)

4- Another StackOverflow subject that might help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448811/calculate-total-cpu-usage)

From that i think you can lead yourself to the solution.

Comment: I could not have said it any better myself mate!

Comment: #1 doesn't really help at all,

#2  /proc/cpuinfo only returns total static system values, not dynamic values such as current usage. I need realtime values.

#3 relates to #2

#4 They're using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this before and my solution was to write a file parser for the system files /proc/cpuinfo and /proc/meminfo, but I don't know how portable this is (worked on both Ubuntu and Scientific Linux for me).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to follow three steps:

1) use system() or popen() to invoke shell command or utility from your program. (refer: [this](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/C/system/shell_commands.html))

2) Decide on a utility from [this list](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-find-out-linux-cpu-utilization.html), to generate utilization data.

3) capture this data from program and parse it to gather relevant info.

Comment: Thanks. This is not helpful. I too checked Google search results before publicly asking here.

Answer (score 0):

[hwloc](http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) could be what you are searching for. It is opensource and it looks that it even supports several platforms.